# @override error showing up in .xml file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

I've just moved my button onCreatView from my `activity_main.java` file to the correct file - my `ConvertFragment.java` file.

Now that I've copy and pasted the code, I'm getting a red-x errors on all of my `findViewById's`... any thoughts?

thanks in advance!

```
public class ConvertFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_convert, container, false);
        final EditText editDecimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDecimal);
        final EditText editBinary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBinary);
        Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int decimal = Integer.valueOf(editDecimal.getText().toString());
                editBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(decimal));
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because a fragment doesn't have a method `findViewById()`.

<strike>You can either call that method on your activity:</strike>

```
getActivity().findViewById()
```

Or just use the layout that you've just inflated and find view's inside of it:

```
rootView.findViewById()
```

The 2nd one is better (IMO) as it doesn't rely on the activity.

Comment: And, you sir, i love! Thank you!

Comment: I would stay far away from that first approach. As an exercise: imagine what happens if you start using more than one instance of the same fragment in a single activity... Or an activity that hosts different fragments that declare the same view IDs.

Comment: @MH. great examples! Haven't thought about them when answering.